# how to split DETAILS row verticaly in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to prepare a Crystal Report document. I have to split the document into two vertical panes. My document has 20 lines(10 on left pane,10 on right pane) to print like below

How can I split the document like below? I have tried to split the document by changing Secion Expert -> Details -> Layout. But it print first 10 rows in the first print, and the rest of the lines are printed on a new print.

Please give me an idea how to do this?

[image]

Comment: Another way is to duplicate the details section and underlay them. So records < 10 go on the original section, records >10 go on the underlayed section, messy but effective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alec was going the right way but he forgot about set up few more thing. On this picture you got all steps how to make it. Section expert of `details` then check Format with Multiple Columns and section Layout should appear. Click on Layout and enter value for width style (21cm / columns of your data)

[image: Setup]

Explanation: Crystal needs to know how much space you are giving him for each column (since `A4` format is `29.7 x 21cm`) then u put half of it (nearly `10 cm` cuz of margins etc.) and then your columns should be separated.

NOTE : if u put 5cm for Detail size then u get 4 columns etc...

Hope it helps

Comment: I had to change my WIDTH. thanks alot for a bried explanation

Answer (score 1):

In the section expert, under details there should be an option for "Format with Multiple Columns".

This will then make a 3rd "Layout" tab available as below, if you play around here you should be able to get the desired output.

[image]

**EDIT**

Another way is to duplicate the details section and underlay them. So records < 10 go on the original section, records >10 go on the underlayed section, messy but effective.

Comment: I tried that but It doesnt do what I want. It prints two columns but the lines are same in two columns.

Comment: I think there are many ways to do it (messy) with suppress, if then logic etc. But it only slows the whole report and maintain that kind of report is hard.

Comment: Not with underlayed sections and Boolean logic, it can't fail. Though it is quite messy as I said