# Two different detail sections side-by-side with two different tables?

Tags: crystal-reports

I use two different excel files in one report. The columns of the excel files are stored in fields. I want to show the columns side-by-side:

Excel Data 1:

```
ID Name
1  Blub
2  Blub2
```

Excel Data 2:

```
ID Income
10  10134
20  134343
```

So the result should look like this:

```
ID Name    ID Income
1  Blub    10  10134
2  Blub2   20  134343
```

I tried it with two different Detail sections (I have to use detail sections) and activate the overlaying of underneath sections for both detail sections.

The result looks like:

```
ID Name    ID Income
1  Blub   
2  Blub2   
           10  ....
           20  ....
```

That is because we use a function model of BW that will give us the data back like this:

```
ExcelFile ID Name  Income
1         1  Blub
1         2  Blub2
2         10        10134
2         20       134343
```

I can not use sub reports and cannot use single fields for each value because there are 100 cells in there...

Does anyone knows a solution?

Comment: NAME and INCOME belongs to same ID or different ? if same u can join these two sheet!!

Comment: different ids :/ the data is not really related to eachother

Answer (score 0):

You have to split your detail row vertically to do that. Something similar already solved by me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31988301/5139222). Be careful when you width of `data size`.

If it doesn't help you enough, feel free to ask with additional questions.

Comment: see new comment :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried it:

Data looked like this:

[image]

After that it looked like this:

[image]

I did a Grouping on the names "GS_FC...." so there are two groups in the report. Than I put the Field which contains the name of the Excel File (GS..._TFCF and GS...._NFD) in the Detail section with this settings:

[image]

[image]

Is this the right thing to do?

Comment: Put `Down then across` on printing direction

Comment: then they are not side by side- they are just unterneath