# Crystal Report - 2 Different Record in 1 Page

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I would like to have 2 different record in 1 page of crystal report.
I have try it myself, but it always show me 1 record in 1 page and another record in second page.

This was the sample of report that what I want.

```
First Page:
Record 1   Record 2
Record 1   Record 2

Second Page:
Record 3   Record 4
Record 3   Record 4
```

Any idea or tips that how this could be done?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split your details into two "**vertical pages**".

Something similar was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31986569/5139222) and was answered by me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31988301/5139222). I think it's the same problem as so it should help you.

Comment: Thanks, I have get it by setting different width for the detail, but it was too crowdy, maybe I should just change the design. ^^

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution can be:

Create two sub reports and place them in parallel on main report. Sub-Report 1 should print all odd records and sub-report 2 should print all even records. This will mimic the visualization that you want.

Comment: This is one way to go. A drawback is that if you have Records with a variable height you will get a mess. I would prefer a multi column setup like @KuKec suggested in his answer.